# Flutter Local routes issue

Tags: flutter, localization

I have a small problem with a flutter local app. I am trying to have 2 routes depending on device  languageCode. When I build the app, that second option are launched. If I save the app, the right route are picked. I think the

```
final lang = locale.languageCode;
```

Do not have a value when this is called:

```
"/newsfeed": lang == "da"
              ? (BuildContext context) => News()
              : (BuildContext context) => NewsEN(),
```

The print statement I have in the code have the right value, so are a bit lost Here are the code:

```
class MyApp3 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        // List all of the app's supported locales here
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en', 'US'),
          Locale('da', 'DK'),
        ],
        // These delegates make sure that the localization data for the proper language is loaded
        localizationsDelegates: [
          // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        // Returns a locale which will be used by the app
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
          // Check if the current device locale is supported
          for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
            //print(locale.languageCode);


            final lang = locale.languageCode;
            print(lang);
            if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {

              return supportedLocale;
            }
          }
          // If the locale of the device is not supported, use the first one
          // from the list (English, in this case).
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        home: MyHomePage(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          //"/Knowledge_pick": (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(),
          "/calculator_pick": (BuildContext context) => Pickcalculator(),
          //"/receipe_pick": (BuildContext context) => Receipemenu(),
            "/receipe_pick": (BuildContext context) => Wrapper(),
          "/newsfeed": lang == "da"
              ? (BuildContext context) => News()
              : (BuildContext context) => NewsEN(),
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't see why this wouldn't work but what you should try to do is setup two different routes, one from 'da' and one for 'en'

```
"/newsfeedDA": (BuildContext context) => News(),
"/newsfeedEN": (BuildContext context) => NewsEN(),
```

and have your logic for selecting them in the initState or constructor of MyHomePage().

Comment: Thanks - This is giving me the same result - It allways give me the "en" version

Comment: How’s are you calling the route in MyHomePage?